# How to query the subcollection of all the users?

Tags: android, database, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

[image: My Firestore Structure]

Here I have one Firestore database collection "attendance". It contains different documents of each class taken for different classes. And each document has few information along with attendees list.

I want to find the attendees status whether they were present or not in a particular subject.

Is there any possible query for it? or do I need to change my structure?

Comment: Querying across multiple sub-collections is not supported by Firestore. But, you can do it for a particular attendance in a details view. I suggest you to change the structure and use root collections that fit almost every structure.

Comment: What do you mean through "I want to find the attendees status"? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, the attendees  collection contains the student status for that particular class i.e. whether the student was present or not.

Comment: Please add also a screenshot of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CollectionReference collectionReferenceImges = firebaseFirestore
                .collection("attandance")
                .document("your attandace document name")
                .collection("attendies");

        Log.d(TAG + "QueryC", String.valueOf(collectionReferenceImges));

        collectionReferenceImges.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {


                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
                }
//


                for (DocumentChange documentChange : Objects.requireNonNull(queryDocumentSnapshots).getDocumentChanges()) {


                }



            }

        });
```

This code is Collection and if you want to access only any particular document then use document reference as similar as collection reference.

Please make sure in collection reference last reference for collection and in document reference last reference is for document.